# play framewrok 1.2.5 script tag not found file

Tags: playframework

i use play framework 1.2.5,and use script tag
it is [image]

and the html is
[image]
but it throw error,
[image]

what is wrong with it?
i read the script tag,[image]and the echart-all.js is really in the public/javascripts/echarts folder.so what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add to conf/routes file

```
GET     /echarts/pieCharts  staticFile:/public/javascripts/echarts/echarts-all.js
```

and change the html

```
<script src="/echarts/pieCharts""></script>
```

it works!

> Serving static resources staticDir: mapping Use the special action
>   staticDir, to point to each folder you wish to publish as a static
>   resources container. staticFile: mapping You can also directly map a
>   URL path to a static file rendering.

reference https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/routes